# Android draw own seekbar thumb in XML

Tags: android

Please help to define own XML drawable for SeekBar Thumb.
In this XML drawable I would like to define custom shapes for `state_selected` and `state_pressed`.

As I understand, in the SeekBar definition in XML we have to put `android:thumb="@drawable/listview_bg_selector"` where `listview_bg_selector` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_default" /> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_clicked"
        />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_thumb_selected" 
         />
</selector>
```

But what to do next, I've tried here code from drawables with shapes, but nothing worked properly, I just saw default SeekBar.
Are there any examples for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future answer-seekers, I used [holo-colors.com](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to create my own custom `SeekBar`, which I am perfectly satisfied with.

They also provide functions to create other android elements such as `Spinner`, `Switch`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, it is a great idea! Also I found that it is available as plugin for IntelliJ and Android Studio https://github.com/jeromevdl/android-holo-colors-idea-plugin

Answer (score 3):

something like this solved the problem for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/seek_thumb_pic">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
    </item>

</selector>
```

another way might be setting bounds in code but I`m not sure about this.